# Largest product in a series - Project Euler #8

Tags: c++

PROBLEM:

The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

---

(C++)

Hello,

I wrote a code that works when trying to find the greater multiple of four adjacent numbers, but it stops working when I try to modify it for 13 adjacent numbers. I've checked it multiple times and don't know what I'm doing wrong. It outputs "2091059712"  instead of "23514624000"  Thanks for the help.

This is the code I made.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    vector<int> v1 = {7,3,1,6,7,1,7,6,5,3,1,3,3,0,6,2,4,9,1,9,2,2,5,1,1,9,6,7,4,4,2,6,5,7,4,7,4,2,3,5,5,3,4,9,1,9,4,9,3,4,
                      9,6,9,8,3,5,2,0,3,1,2,7,7,4,5,0,6,3,2,6,2,3,9,5,7,8,3,1,8,0,1,6,9,8,4,8,0,1,8,6,9,4,7,8,8,5,1,8,4,3,
                      8,5,8,6,1,5,6,0,7,8,9,1,1,2,9,4,9,4,9,5,4,5,9,5,0,1,7,3,7,9,5,8,3,3,1,9,5,2,8,5,3,2,0,8,8,0,5,5,1,1,
                      1,2,5,4,0,6,9,8,7,4,7,1,5,8,5,2,3,8,6,3,0,5,0,7,1,5,6,9,3,2,9,0,9,6,3,2,9,5,2,2,7,4,4,3,0,4,3,5,5,7,
                      6,6,8,9,6,6,4,8,9,5,0,4,4,5,2,4,4,5,2,3,1,6,1,7,3,1,8,5,6,4,0,3,0,9,8,7,1,1,1,2,1,7,2,2,3,8,3,1,1,3,
                      6,2,2,2,9,8,9,3,4,2,3,3,8,0,3,0,8,1,3,5,3,3,6,2,7,6,6,1,4,2,8,2,8,0,6,4,4,4,4,8,6,6,4,5,2,3,8,7,4,9,
                      3,0,3,5,8,9,0,7,2,9,6,2,9,0,4,9,1,5,6,0,4,4,0,7,7,2,3,9,0,7,1,3,8,1,0,5,1,5,8,5,9,3,0,7,9,6,0,8,6,6,
                      7,0,1,7,2,4,2,7,1,2,1,8,8,3,9,9,8,7,9,7,9,0,8,7,9,2,2,7,4,9,2,1,9,0,1,6,9,9,7,2,0,8,8,8,0,9,3,7,7,6,
                      6,5,7,2,7,3,3,3,0,0,1,0,5,3,3,6,7,8,8,1,2,2,0,2,3,5,4,2,1,8,0,9,7,5,1,2,5,4,5,4,0,5,9,4,7,5,2,2,4,3,
                      5,2,5,8,4,9,0,7,7,1,1,6,7,0,5,5,6,0,1,3,6,0,4,8,3,9,5,8,6,4,4,6,7,0,6,3,2,4,4,1,5,7,2,2,1,5,5,3,9,7,
                      5,3,6,9,7,8,1,7,9,7,7,8,4,6,1,7,4,0,6,4,9,5,5,1,4,9,2,9,0,8,6,2,5,6,9,3,2,1,9,7,8,4,6,8,6,2,2,4,8,2,
                      8,3,9,7,2,2,4,1,3,7,5,6,5,7,0,5,6,0,5,7,4,9,0,2,6,1,4,0,7,9,7,2,9,6,8,6,5,2,4,1,4,5,3,5,1,0,0,4,7,4,
                      8,2,1,6,6,3,7,0,4,8,4,4,0,3,1,9,9,8,9,0,0,0,8,8,9,5,2,4,3,4,5,0,6,5,8,5,4,1,2,2,7,5,8,8,6,6,6,8,8,1,
                      1,6,4,2,7,1,7,1,4,7,9,9,2,4,4,4,2,9,2,8,2,3,0,8,6,3,4,6,5,6,7,4,8,1,3,9,1,9,1,2,3,1,6,2,8,2,4,5,8,6,
                      1,7,8,6,6,4,5,8,3,5,9,1,2,4,5,6,6,5,2,9,4,7,6,5,4,5,6,8,2,8,4,8,9,1,2,8,8,3,1,4,2,6,0,7,6,9,0,0,4,2,
                      2,4,2,1,9,0,2,2,6,7,1,0,5,5,6,2,6,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,9,3,7,0,5,4,4,2,1,7,5,0,6,9,4,1,6,5,8,9,6,0,4,0,8,
                      0,7,1,9,8,4,0,3,8,5,0,9,6,2,4,5,5,4,4,4,3,6,2,9,8,1,2,3,0,9,8,7,8,7,9,9,2,7,2,4,4,2,8,4,9,0,9,1,8,8,
                      8,4,5,8,0,1,5,6,1,6,6,0,9,7,9,1,9,1,3,3,8,7,5,4,9,9,2,0,0,5,2,4,0,6,3,6,8,9,9,1,2,5,6,0,7,1,7,6,0,6,
                      0,5,8,8,6,1,1,6,4,6,7,1,0,9,4,0,5,0,7,7,5,4,1,0,0,2,2,5,6,9,8,3,1,5,5,2,0,0,0,5,5,9,3,5,7,2,9,7,2,5,
                      7,1,6,3,6,2,6,9,5,6,1,8,8,2,6,7,0,4,2,8,2,5,2,4,8,3,6,0,0,8,2,3,2,5,7,5,3,0,4,2,0,7,5,2,9,6,3,4,5,0,};


int max_product = 0, multiplication, i = 0;

    while (i< size(v1) -13){

        multiplication = v1[i] * v1[i+1] * v1[i+2] * v1[i+3]; //* v1[i+4] * v1[i+5] * v1[i+6] * v1[i+7] * v1[i+8] * v1[i+9] * v1[i+10] * v1[i+11] * v1[i+12];

        i++;
    if (multiplication>max_product){
        max_product=multiplication;
}
    }
   // cout << "The greatest product is: " << max_product << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int max_product = 0,` -- Your code will fail if there is a sequence like `9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9`.  That will probably overflow what an `int` can store.  Also, you could optimize the code by sliding over any 13 digit entries that have 0, since you know multiplying by 0 will give you 0.

Comment: Sidenote, try utilizing the standard library, like `std::reduce`/`std::accumulate` to calculate `multiplication`.

Comment: In addition to skipping zeroes, you can compute the solution in O(N) time regardless of how many digits need to be multiplied together, where N is the length of the input. That's because at each step you can update the product by dividing out the left-most digit from the previous sliding window and multiplying in the new right-most digit. After skipping zeroes, you compute a full product, but because you will never do that for any overlapping sequence of digits it remains linear no matter how many zeroes or non-zeroes the input contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without applying the optimizations suggested in the comments (skipping the zeros in the sequence, and dividing / multiplying the leftmost and rightmost digit in the window of 13 integers), simply changing the type to `uint64_t` for all of your integer types yields the correct answer.

The reason is that there are sequences of 13 integers that when multiplied, will overflow the maximum value of an `int`. Using `uint64_t`, an unsigned 64-bit type, there is no longer the risk of overflow, since `9^13` fits within this integer type.

Here is the code, with a few changes that utilize the STL algorithm and numeric functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>

int main() {

    std::vector<uint64_t> v1 = {7,3,1,6,7,1,7,6,5,3,1,3,3,0,6,2,4,9,1,9,2,2,5,1,1,9,6,7,4,4,2,6,5,7,4,7,4,2,3,5,5,3,4,9,1,9,4,9,3,4,
                      9,6,9,8,3,5,2,0,3,1,2,7,7,4,5,0,6,3,2,6,2,3,9,5,7,8,3,1,8,0,1,6,9,8,4,8,0,1,8,6,9,4,7,8,8,5,1,8,4,3,
                      8,5,8,6,1,5,6,0,7,8,9,1,1,2,9,4,9,4,9,5,4,5,9,5,0,1,7,3,7,9,5,8,3,3,1,9,5,2,8,5,3,2,0,8,8,0,5,5,1,1,
                      1,2,5,4,0,6,9,8,7,4,7,1,5,8,5,2,3,8,6,3,0,5,0,7,1,5,6,9,3,2,9,0,9,6,3,2,9,5,2,2,7,4,4,3,0,4,3,5,5,7,
                      6,6,8,9,6,6,4,8,9,5,0,4,4,5,2,4,4,5,2,3,1,6,1,7,3,1,8,5,6,4,0,3,0,9,8,7,1,1,1,2,1,7,2,2,3,8,3,1,1,3,
                      6,2,2,2,9,8,9,3,4,2,3,3,8,0,3,0,8,1,3,5,3,3,6,2,7,6,6,1,4,2,8,2,8,0,6,4,4,4,4,8,6,6,4,5,2,3,8,7,4,9,
                      3,0,3,5,8,9,0,7,2,9,6,2,9,0,4,9,1,5,6,0,4,4,0,7,7,2,3,9,0,7,1,3,8,1,0,5,1,5,8,5,9,3,0,7,9,6,0,8,6,6,
                      7,0,1,7,2,4,2,7,1,2,1,8,8,3,9,9,8,7,9,7,9,0,8,7,9,2,2,7,4,9,2,1,9,0,1,6,9,9,7,2,0,8,8,8,0,9,3,7,7,6,
                      6,5,7,2,7,3,3,3,0,0,1,0,5,3,3,6,7,8,8,1,2,2,0,2,3,5,4,2,1,8,0,9,7,5,1,2,5,4,5,4,0,5,9,4,7,5,2,2,4,3,
                      5,2,5,8,4,9,0,7,7,1,1,6,7,0,5,5,6,0,1,3,6,0,4,8,3,9,5,8,6,4,4,6,7,0,6,3,2,4,4,1,5,7,2,2,1,5,5,3,9,7,
                      5,3,6,9,7,8,1,7,9,7,7,8,4,6,1,7,4,0,6,4,9,5,5,1,4,9,2,9,0,8,6,2,5,6,9,3,2,1,9,7,8,4,6,8,6,2,2,4,8,2,
                      8,3,9,7,2,2,4,1,3,7,5,6,5,7,0,5,6,0,5,7,4,9,0,2,6,1,4,0,7,9,7,2,9,6,8,6,5,2,4,1,4,5,3,5,1,0,0,4,7,4,
                      8,2,1,6,6,3,7,0,4,8,4,4,0,3,1,9,9,8,9,0,0,0,8,8,9,5,2,4,3,4,5,0,6,5,8,5,4,1,2,2,7,5,8,8,6,6,6,8,8,1,
                      1,6,4,2,7,1,7,1,4,7,9,9,2,4,4,4,2,9,2,8,2,3,0,8,6,3,4,6,5,6,7,4,8,1,3,9,1,9,1,2,3,1,6,2,8,2,4,5,8,6,
                      1,7,8,6,6,4,5,8,3,5,9,1,2,4,5,6,6,5,2,9,4,7,6,5,4,5,6,8,2,8,4,8,9,1,2,8,8,3,1,4,2,6,0,7,6,9,0,0,4,2,
                      2,4,2,1,9,0,2,2,6,7,1,0,5,5,6,2,6,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,9,3,7,0,5,4,4,2,1,7,5,0,6,9,4,1,6,5,8,9,6,0,4,0,8,
                      0,7,1,9,8,4,0,3,8,5,0,9,6,2,4,5,5,4,4,4,3,6,2,9,8,1,2,3,0,9,8,7,8,7,9,9,2,7,2,4,4,2,8,4,9,0,9,1,8,8,
                      8,4,5,8,0,1,5,6,1,6,6,0,9,7,9,1,9,1,3,3,8,7,5,4,9,9,2,0,0,5,2,4,0,6,3,6,8,9,9,1,2,5,6,0,7,1,7,6,0,6,
                      0,5,8,8,6,1,1,6,4,6,7,1,0,9,4,0,5,0,7,7,5,4,1,0,0,2,2,5,6,9,8,3,1,5,5,2,0,0,0,5,5,9,3,5,7,2,9,7,2,5,
                      7,1,6,3,6,2,6,9,5,6,1,8,8,2,6,7,0,4,2,8,2,5,2,4,8,3,6,0,0,8,2,3,2,5,7,5,3,0,4,2,0,7,5,2,9,6,3,4,5,0,};


    uint64_t max_product = 0, multiplication, i = 0;

    while (i < size(v1) -13)
    {
        multiplication = std::accumulate(v1.begin() + i, 
                                         v1.begin() + i + 13, 
                                         uint64_t{1}, std::multiplies<uint64_t>());
        max_product = std::max(multiplication, max_product);
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << "The greatest product is: " << max_product << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The greatest product is: 23514624000
```

Note the usage of `std::accumulate` and the `std::multiplies` function object instead of the long sequence of multiplications you were doing.  In addition, the `std::max` function determines the maximum during each iteration.